Why am I intermittently receiving "temporarily_unavailable" errors from LinkedIn OAuth v2 API?
I have an existing application that uses LinkedIn's OAuth v2 API for user authentication. Recently, I’ve started intermittently receiving temporarily_unavailable errors when attempting to obtain an authorization token via the endpoint https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization.
Here’s the flow I am following:

User clicks the LinkedIn login button.
User is redirected to https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization with the following parameters:


response_type=code
client_id=CLIENT_ID
redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI
state=uuid
scope=r_liteprofile%20r_emailaddress


LinkedIn shows a screen with the message, 'Bummer, something went wrong. In five seconds, you will be redirected to: my_redirect_uri.'

This intermittent issue is impacting the authentication flow for some users. Here’s what I’ve done so far to troubleshoot:

Verified that all parameters are correct.
Tested with different user accounts and at different times of the day.
Checked LinkedIn’s API status for any service disruptions.

Has anyone else encountered this issue or does anyone have suggestions on how to resolve or mitigate this problem?
Thank you for your assistance!
#linkedin
I tried:

Verified that all parameters are correct.
Tested with different user accounts and at different times of the day.
Checked LinkedIn’s API status for any service disruptions.

I expect to know why I'm getting the error 'temporarily_unavailable' and what I should do to avoid getting this error in the future.
